# JSON post on PHP CURL

Tags: arrays, json, curl

i need to upload my file to server using json post data
format server accept is :

```
"fields": [{
            "external": {
                "name": "file",
                "filename": "myfile",
                "put": {},
                "size": 3895557
            }
        },
```

My code is :

```
Array
                        (
                            'external' => Array
                                (
                                    'name' => 'file',
                                    'filename' => 'myfile',
                                    'put' => new stdClass(),                                    
                                    'size' => $filesize
                                )
                        ),
```

but i can not upload my file.i guess there is problem with 'put' syntax ?

thanks

Comment: thanks but problem is not about json format. any help about it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand well your question. You want to upload a file using a JSON post request. A JSON post is when the server is expecting to receive a JSON encoded data. Well, you must know that it is impossible to upload a file using a JSON post, simply because JSON does not support file type. The value being JSON encoded/decoded can be anything except a resource.

Maybe you are trying to connect with a RESTfull/RESTlike API that returns a JSON response. I guess what you refer to as `fields` is the JSON response:

```
[{
  "external": {
       "name": "file",
       "filename": "myfile",
       "put": {},
       "size": 3895557
   }
 },
...]
```

From this response, it can be concluded that the API accepts multiple uploads. The server returns a brief description for each file uploaded. I guess that it gives you also a link, under the `put` key, where you can update the file uploaded (I am guessing).

It's pretty simple to upload a file with curl, all you have to do is put the `@` symbol before the realpath of the file.

Following an example showing how to perform a simple upload of a document using curl over php:

```
$target_url = url;
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('target_file');
$post_fields = array('file'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Note: You should perform a Content-Type negotiation to determine the types accepted by the server. Remember that the Content-Type defines the MIME Type of the served document.

Hope it's useful!